# Question mark equals, doesn't work on php

Tags: php

this is my php code:

```
<html><body>Hey!: <?= "World";?></body></html>
```

It just prints "Hey!:" Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short tags (which you're using here) can be turned on or off depending on the server you're running the code on. If it's your server, look in php.ini

Comment: Indeed, link in manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Long tags look like this: <?php echo "World";?>

Comment: According to the docs, `<?=` is always available since PHP 5.4.0

Answer (score 3):

You need to set short_open_tag to 1

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 2):

Does your file end in .php and will it execute as php on your webserver? add

```
<?php echo "yes I run php!<br>\n"; ?>
```

to your file to be sure. View source to see what happened to the php tags. Then maybe switch on short tags as the other answers told you to.