# <?=expression?> doesn't work in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark equals, doesn't work on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277587/question-mark-equals-doesnt-work-on-php)

```
<?php $a=123; ?>
<?=$a?>
```

This code is supposed to print "123" on the page. However nothing is printed.
Anyone know what can cause this problem?

Comment: Note: this is not generally considered portable code. You should use `<?php echo $a; ?>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your PHP.INI file for `short_open_tag`. It might be set to off, turn this option to `On`

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Comment: +1. Also, to be absolutely sure that your code will work regardless of environment don't use `<?`, but always `<?php`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a server configuration issue. You need to enable the  **short_open_tag** directive in your server's PHP configuration. See the PHP manual for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

This only applies if your server's PHP version is < 5.4.0. Also, you cannot change this using the **ini_set** function. You will need to modify the server PHP configuration because it's a per-directory setting and the PHP engine needs to know the state of this setting before parsing a script.