# MySQL showing latest and not what needed

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a MySQL database which contains a section 'category' and 'twit_info' inside the 'twit_info' i have 'cat_id' and inside 'category' i have 'cat_id' and 'cat_name'

But for some reason when outputting this code it shows me the latest 'cat_name' of the latest 'cat_id'

But i want it to show the 'cat_name' from the 'cat_id' im linking. How can i get this to work here is my code im outputting which shows it.

```
<?php if ($row['cat_id'] > 0): ?>
    <div class="meta">
    <small class="float-left gray">
    From Recent Events: <a href="<?=$u?>categories/<?=$row['cat_id']?>/1"><?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_name'])?></a>
    </small>
    </div>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

And below is what calls the database i think.

```
     if(isset($_GET['catid']) and $_GET['catid'] !=''){
     $str = "SELECT * FROM twit_info where cat_id = ". $_GET['catid'] ." order by date_submitted desc";
     $str_cat = "SELECT * FROM category where cat_id = ". $_GET['catid'] ;
     }
     else{
     $str = "SELECT * FROM twit_info where cat_id = (select max(cat_id) from twit_info order by date_submitted desc) and cat_id !=0";
      $str_cat = "SELECT * FROM category where cat_id = (select distinct max(cat_id) from twit_info)";
     }
             $twit = dbConnect($str);
            //if(mysql_num_rows($twit)>0){
              $cat_info = dbConnect($str_cat);  
              $cat_record = mysql_fetch_array($cat_info);
              //print_r($cat_record);
            // }
```

So how can i get that php code uptop to display the correct cat_name' for that 'cat_id'

I think its because `<?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_name'])?>` isnt calling it right? In the html?

Basically the issue is `<?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_name'])?>` is not outputting what is associated to the `cat_id`

Comment: if(isset($_GET['catid']) and $_GET['catid'] !=''){...
is $_GET['catid'] set? does the url have ?catid=xxx at all?

Comment: Url work as follows `domain.com/categories/<?=$row['cat_id']?>/1`

Comment: Then the answer is no, unless you have something converting that URI segment into a get var. .htaccess could do that, some URI parsers could. add ?catid=1 to the url and see what happens. If it does what you want then the problem is in how you are handling reading the uri parameters

Comment: Basically the issue is `<?=stripslashes($cat_record['cat_name'])?>` is not outputting what is associated to the `cat_id`

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, your problem may be short_open_tag is not set to 1 in your php.ini so things like `<?=` will do nothing

HOWEVER, it is recommended you don't use shortcode to echo statements in php. You should be using `<?php echo` instead.

This post may help:

[Question mark equals, doesn't work on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277587/question-mark-equals-doesnt-work-on-php)

I'm obligated to give the standard speech on switching to PDO and ceasing use of mysql_ functions. In general that's the expected progress of php standards, sort of like not using `<?=` anymore.

*EDIT*

Returning to the original assumption, it is possible your URI handling is not reading that parameter as `$_GET['catid']`.

What happens when you `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: No thats fine the whole site uses <?= and works fine. Its basically i think im not calling the correct table or something.

Comment: fair enough, what does print_r($cat_record) result in?

Comment: @KaiQing - FYI, since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available, I wouldn't call it bad practice these days.

Comment: What I mean is, are you calling the first $str_cat in the $_GET conditional or the second one in the else?

Comment: From Recent Events: Array ( [0] => 5 [cat_id] => 5 [1] => CAT NAME [cat_name] => CAT NAME [2] => HERE IS THE DESCRIPTION [cat_desc] => HERE IS THE DESCRIPTION ) 1

Comment: I just dont think its pulling the cat_name from the cat_id

Comment: Is there a reason to use $cat_record['cat_name'] and not $row['cat_name']?

Comment: I think its because 'cat_name' isnt in that row its in another table

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the kind of thing we can extrapolate from this snippet. You should be able to inspect the database and see what is available. Your query and print_r results suggest it is in the table and should display as expected, unless that particular row does not have a name in that field. Either way, a few rounds of print_r might clarify all of that for you.

Comment: Okay i understand im gonna try to look into it more. Thought it was somethign wrong with my code possibly.

Comment: Ill post if i have any success here.